# ООП в функциях

Tags: ооп, php

Доброго времени суток!

При использовании ООП в функции мне выходит ошибка, как можно использовать функции ООП в обычной функции? То есть:

```
class test {
    public function test($text) {
        print $text;
    }
}

$test = new test();

function test2($text) {
    print $test->test($text);
}
```

Comment: эмм..а что такое "ООП в функции"?

Comment: у вас явная путаница в понятиях

Comment: Вообще ООП - это теоретические понятия, которые практически в PHP реализованны в виде классов и объектов. Поэтому правильней сказать "использование объектов или классов(static которые имеют) в других функциях", а то у людей начинается ступор и недопонимание, что за ООП в функции.

Comment: В описание тоже самое встречается, ну это так, к сведению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

Сделал `test::test('Text')` вместо `$test->test('Text')`

Answer (score 3):

Метод test класса test, уже имеет команду print. Поэтому для вывода информации достаточно просто вызвать `$test->test($text);` без print.

Или в методе test заменить print $text; на return $text;

Также можно метод test сделать статическим если он будет только выводить поступающую информацию. Тогда код будет таким:

```
class test{
    public static function test($text){
        print $text;
    }
}

function text($text){
    test::test($text);
}
```

Статические (static) методы классов, можно вызывать без инициализации самого класса ($test = new test).

Дополнение:

файл db.php

```
class db{
    public function db($query){
        query($query);
    }
}
```

файл function.php

```
function test($query){
    $db = new db;
    $db->db($query);
}
```

файл index.php

```
include db.php;
include function.php

test($query);
```

Как то так.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: кто вам такое сказал? если класс инициализирован внутри функции то можно.

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку угадывать? :)
Вангую, что в функции надо сделать еще одну строчку с `global $test;` :)

---

```
<?php
class test {
    public function test($text = '') {
        print $text;
    }
}

$test = new test();

function test2($text) {
    global $test;
    $test->test($text);
}
test2('111');
?>
```

без ошибок, все ок

Comment: Не надо троллить...

Comment: будет работать, почему же нет? большинство сайтов так и работает :)

Comment: В ответе выше написана разница. test::test() нельзя использовать для записи ибо static, $test->test() можно